# How to skip an iteration that has an error?

Tags: vba, catia

I created a nice macro for CATIA V5, that make some geometrical parameters increase in a loop, and save the file for each case.

Unfortunately, there are some combinations that won't work and create errors in catia itself.
Until know I used On error Resume Next.

But I would prefere that if there is an error, it saves it as the previous, errorless, file

here is a part of my code :

```
For i = 1 To 10
strParam2.Value = Val(i) * 1
part1.Update
On Error Resume Next
folderpath3 = folderpath2 & "\" & "file" & i
MkDir folderpath3
name = folderpath3 & "\" & "file" & i
partDocument1.ExportData name, "CATPart"
```

If someone has an idea, I would be grateful!
matthieu

Comment: Are you getting an error on the `MkDir` line or the `ExportData` line? (Remove `On Error Resume Next`) - When you get the error, click debug, and then look at the values of your variables. Are they what you expect them to be? I dont see you ever gave `folderpath2` a value either.

Comment: Error comes from part.update, because the CAD software can't create the geometry. The code works all the time

Comment: The idea would be to come back to the latest working iteration if there is an error, and then continue

Comment: Can you post the full code - to me it is not clear what the last iteration could be. When is part1 set?

Answer (score 0):

You should save a last known correct value if the part can be updated and then use this value if you have an error on Update. You should initialize `lastCorrectValue` to a value which will always work. I don't know what type do you use, so I just initialized it to an Integer with the value of 5.

```
Dim lastCorrectValue as Integer
lastCorrectValue = 5

For i = 1 To 10
  strParam2.Value = Val(i) * 1
  On Error Resume Next
  part1.Update
  If Err = 0 Then GoTo Continue
  strParam2.Value = lastCorrectValue
  part1.Update
Continue:
  lastCorrectValue = strParam2.Value
  folderpath3 = folderpath2 & "\" & "file" & i
  MkDir folderpath3
  name = folderpath3 & "\" & "file" & i
  partDocument1.ExportData name, "CATPart"
Next i
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help. Indeed I always have a correct value. So it sworks fine. but considering i'm going to plot graphs later on, if the error value is 9, coming back to 1 for exemple might be a problem, but it would zork if lastcorrect value=val(i-1)

Comment: @Matthieu You yourself said that you want to use a last known value in a comment to your question. If you changed your mind, you should then say so. Maybe you should first better define what exactly do you want and then update your question or ask a new one, since this answer answers your question.